# Looking to find duplicates using DIFFERENCE() among 2+ columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL Select query that uses the DIFFERENCE() function to find similar names in a database to identify duplicates.

The short version of the code I'm using is:

```
SELECT *, DIFFERENCE(FirstName, LEAD(FirstName)  OVER (ORDER BY SOUNDEX(FirstName))) d
WHERE d >= 3
```

The problem is my database has additional columns that include middle names and nicknames. So if I have a customer who has multiple names they go by, they might be in the database multiple times, and I need to compare a variety of columns against each other.

Sample Data:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|ID  |First   |Middle  |AKA1    |AKA2    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|1   |Sally   |Ann     |NULL    |NULL    |
|2   |Ann     |NULL    |NULL    |NULL    |
|3   |Sue     |NULL    |NULL    |NULL    |
|4   |Suzy    |NULL    |NULL    |NULL    |
|5   |Patricia|NULL    |Trish   |Patty   |
|6   |Patty   |NULL    |Patricia|Trish   |
|7   |Trish   |NULL    |Patty   |Patricia|
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

In the above, rows 1+2 are duplicates of each other, as are 3+4, and 5+6+7.

So I'm not sure the best way to get what I want.  Here's the longer version of the code I'm actually using:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT *,
    SOUNDEX(FirstName) AS "FirstSoundex",
    SOUNDEX(LastName) AS "LastSoundex",
    LAG (SOUNDEX(FirstName)) OVER (ORDER BY SOUNDEX(FirstName)) AS "PreviousFirstSoundex",
    LAG (SOUNDEX(LastName)) OVER (ORDER BY SOUNDEX(LastName)) AS "PreviousLastSoundex"
    FROM Clients),

B AS (
    SELECT *,
    ISNULL(DIFFERENCE(FirstName, LEAD(FirstName)  OVER (ORDER BY FirstSoundex)),0) AS "FirstScore",
    ISNULL(DIFFERENCE(LastName, LEAD(LastName)  OVER (ORDER BY LastSoundex)),0) AS "LastScore"
    FROM A),

C AS (
    SELECT *,
        ISNULL(LAG (FirstScore) OVER (ORDER BY FirstSoundex),0) AS "PreviousFirstScore",
        ISNULL(LAG (LastScore) OVER (ORDER BY LastSoundex),0) AS "PreviousLastScore"
    FROM B
    ),

D AS (
    SELECT *,
        (CASE WHEN (PreviousFirstScore >=3 AND PreviousLastScore >=3) THEN (PreviousFirstSoundex + PreviousLastSoundex)
            WHEN (FirstScore >= 3 AND LastScore >=3) THEN (FirstSoundex + LastSoundex)
            END) AS "GroupName"
    FROM C
    WHERE ((PreviousFirstScore >=3 AND PreviousLastScore >=3) OR (FirstScore >= 3 AND LastScore >=3))
    )

SELECT *,
        LAG(GroupName) OVER (ORDER BY GroupName) AS "PreviousGroup",
        LEAD(GroupName) OVER (ORDER BY GroupName) AS "NextGroup"
    FROM D

WHERE (D.GroupName = D.PreviousGroup OR D.GroupName = D.NextGroup)
```

This lets me group together bundles of potential duplicates and it works well for me. However, I now want to add in a way to check against multiple columns, and I don't know how to do that.

I was thinking about creating a union, something like:

```
    SELECT ClientID,
        LastName,
        FirstName AS "TempName"
        FROM Clients
    UNION
    SELECT ClientID,
        LastName,
        MiddleName AS "TempName"
        FROM Clients
        WHERE MiddleName IS NOT NULL
...etc
```

But then my LAG() and LEAD() wouldn't work because I'd have multiple rows with the same ClientID. I don't want to identify a single Client as a duplicate of itself.

Anyways, any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  `DIFFERENCE()` on first name without the last name doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: Have you looked into using COALESCE with your columns? COALESCE keeps looking until if finds a non-NULL value. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am testing DIFFERENCE on both first name AND last name, just separately. If I made a string that was JohnSmith (both names combined) and ran DIFFERENCE on it, it would only get me the first few consonants. So I am looking for similar first name AND similar last name.

Comment: @CriticalError unfortunately, I want to look at all the values, not just the first non-null one. So for example, a client could have two nicknames, or a nickname and a middle name, and I want to compare all of them, not just the first one I come across.